# could not access library via CSOM/REST API if end user only has permission on the library but not the web level

Tags: permissions, client-object-model, csom

This is on SharePoint Online and here are the env setup:

- Site collection: `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection1` - End user has Permission
- Subsite: `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection1/subsite1`   - No permission
- Library: `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection1/subsite1/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx`    - Has Permission

So basically end user has permission on site collection, not on sub site, but has permission on a library under the sub site. End user could access the library from browser.

Right now, we are facing a challenge to access the library via SharePoint CSOM and REST API:

- The query of the list collection from that sub site is failing with access denied error.
- we could not get that library directly by using `context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryTitle)` via [CSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcollection.getbytitle.aspx)
- [`Web.GetList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getlist.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is not working, with similar access denied error
- REST API is failing with similar access denied error as well, here is a sample query: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=Id,Title`

Note for above 1 and 2, we have a valid sub site web reference, thus allow us to execute the CSOM call on that sub site. but we could not query any information on that sub site such as web id.

So we are running out of approaches right now, just wonder if anyone could shed some lights about what we could do here. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: What permission is granted on the library? Is it a permission that allows for using Remote Interfaces? It isn't clear as to what you have it set to.

Comment: thanks @EricAlexander  End user has Read permission on the library which includes remote interface permissions after I checked the Read permission level on that sub site. It has Limited Access on the sub site which should be due to Read permission on library.

Comment: Does it work if you have the list guid instead of title? `/_api/web/lists(guid'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx')`
If not, you'll have to create a permission level that allows the user to query the site using remote interfaces.

Comment: one other question, does the site have the Limited-access user permission lockdown mode feature enabled in `/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site`?

Comment: thanks @wjervis, we tried with "remote interface" permission level, it didn't work.  Eric's suggestion works like a charm after I deactivated that feature. Thanks very much. I guess that question would be how to explain this to our customer